Outlook EWS api operation GetItem is failing to return mime content
The request is failing to return mime content for single occurrence of a recurring meeting, but able to return the mime content with series of occurrences. Please find the request and corresponding response.

Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
<RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
<t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
<AdditionalProperties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
</AdditionalProperties>
</ItemShape>
<ItemIds>
<t:ItemId Id ="AAMkADkwMmEzMTRlLTg2ZTItNGRjMS1hM2Q1LTBkNDFiZTQ3Mjg4ZAFRAAgI3H3f87oAAEYAAAAAV6Y26yf9uEuy2zFUh+2HaAcAyemTzzY03USgkruIo6kNeQAAAAABDQAAyemTzzY03USgkruIo6kNeQABfzU2SAAAEA=="
/>
</ItemIds>
</GetItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
Response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="7587" MinorBuildNumber="35" Version="V2018_01_08"
xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<m:ResponseMessages>
<m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
<m:MessageText>Data is corrupt., Store ID 'CAjcfd/zugAARgAAAABXpjbrJ/24S7LbMVSH7YdoBwDJ6ZPPNjTdRKCSu4ijqQ15AAAAAAENAADJ6ZPPNjTdRKCSu4ijqQ15AAF/NTZIAAAQ'
with type 'Message' isn't an ID of a folder, item or
mailbox.</m:MessageText>
<m:ResponseCode>ErrorCorruptData</m:ResponseCode>
<m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
<m:Items/>
</m:GetItemResponseMessage>
</m:ResponseMessages>
</m:GetItemResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

